# Ionic Selectable showing massive list

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

So I'm using ionic-selectable with select multiple to true.

When I finished selecting the item, a massive of selected items list showing on the website.

How would I customising the display message or just show the number of items selected, instead of a list?

[image]

I want to "14 items selected" not the items

Comment: Could you please your code where you use the `ionSelect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution, you can modify the selectedText attribute

```
<ion-select multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="optionsSelected" [selectedText]="optionsSelected.length +' items selected'">
```

In your .ts file, make sure you initialize the ngModel variable as

```
optionsSelected:any =[];
```

Sample Output

[image: Sample Output]

[Doc Reference](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select)

UPDATE:-

```
<ionic-selectable item-content [(ngModel)]="optionsSelected" itemValueField="id" itemTextField="name" [items]="ports">
            <ng-template ionicSelectableValueTemplate let-port="value">
                {{optionsSelected.length}} &nbsp items selected
            </ng-template>
        </ionic-selectable>
```

[Plugin Docs](https://github.com/eakoriakin/ionic-selectable/wiki#value-template)

Comment: I'm using "ionic-selectable" which is different "ion-select", it does not have the attribute "selectedText"

Comment: so you are using a third party library.. this is from their docs.. this will serve your purpose.. you can modify the text as per the above logic.
https://github.com/eakoriakin/ionic-selectable/wiki#value-template
demo :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-selectable-value-template?file=app/pages/home/home.html

Comment: check the update in the answer above.. and please mention that you are using a third party plugin in your original question..

Answer (score 0):

I made an example using Ionic 5. This could be a bit different between Ionic versions, but if you get the main idea it can be adapted to solve you problem.

This option allows you set anything you want, simple text or specific html.

I had to find the element that change after selection. With vanilla JavaScript, I could get the element and edit it. Here is the snippet code:

**home.page.html**

```html
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
        <ion-label>jps' list</ion-label>
    </ion-list-header>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Multiple list</ion-label>
        <ion-select multiple="true" 
                    cancelText="Cancel" 
                    okText="Ok" 
                    (ionChange)="detectChanges(0)" 
                    [(ngModel)]="optionsSelected">
            <ion-select-option value="1">Option number 1</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="2">Option number 2</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="3">Option number 3</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="4">Option number 4</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="5">Option number 5</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="6">Option number 6</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="7">Option number 7</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="8">Option number 8</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="9">Option number 9</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="10">Option number 10</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="11">Option number 11</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="12">Option number 12</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="13">Option number 13</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="14">Option number 14</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="15">Option number 15</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="16">Option number 16</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="17">Option number 17</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="18">Option number 18</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="19">Option number 19</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="20">Option number 20</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

home.page.ts

````js
    optionsSelected: Array<string> = []

    constructor() {}

    // This param might be the number
    // of the ion-select as currentlly
    // appears on html page.
    //
    // Starting with the number 0
    // ```
    // <ion-select (ionChange)="detectChanges(0)">...</ion-select><!-- I'm number 0 -->
    // <ion-select (ionChange)="detectChanges(1)">...</ion-select><!-- I'm number 1 -->
    // <ion-select (ionChange)="detectChanges(n)">...</ion-select><!-- I'm number n -->
    // ```
    detectChanges(ionSelectNumber) {
        // Just for set in singular o plural word.
        let optionsCount = this.optionsSelected.length

        // Detecting on your page all ion-select tags.
        let doc = document.getElementsByTagName('ion-select')

        // This could be OPTIONAL, only use it when you're not
        // sure that you html page has ion-select components.
        if (!doc) 
            return

        // Here is where magic happens!
        // you already have the element that is displayed it
        // when a user selects any options
        // just change its innerHTML to the shadowRoot
        // because in the version of ionic implements #shadow-root
        // in its elements
        doc[ionSelectNumber].shadowRoot.innerHTML = 
            this.templateData(
                !optionsCount ? '' : optionsCount === 1 ? `${optionsCount} option` : `${optionsCount} options`
            )
    }

    templateData(customText: string) {
        // This is the structure that ionic uses
        // for ion-select in the specific
        // section you want to custom
        //
        // try to print the shadowRoot.innerHTML
        // and you'll get this text.
        return `
            <div class="select-text" part="text">${customText}</div>
            <div class="select-icon" role="presentation" part="icon">
                <div class="select-icon-inner"></div>
            </div>
            <button type="button"></button>`
    }
````

And this is how it looks like:

Ion select before selection:

[image: Ion select before selection]

Ion select after selection:

[image: Ion select after selection]

Comment: any way to add seachbar to the select?

Comment: No, because the searchbar is a component and it needs its own initialization, if you try this option, the possible scenario is a searchbar without functionality, this option can be usable when you want to set some structure that **selectedText** input doesn't allow you, like an image, or a different presentation